# Is there such thing as an ArraySet and ArrayMap?

Tags: java

I would like a map that preserves the order of the elements if there is such a thing.

I am aware that it would *not* perform near as well as a HashMap, but I only plan to use it for small/temporary programs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no ArrayMap.  :)

But a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will preserve the insertion order, and a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) will order based on the keys' natural ordering.

Comment: @broady, where does it say that original poster wants insertion order?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, but I was looking for insertion order. Thanks!

Comment: ArrayMap and ArraySet are in android

Comment: `ArrayMap` does exist, it's in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html

Answer (score 6):

If you mean a defined ordering of the items you can use a `TreeMap` (doc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)).. otherwise if you are talking about insertion order you can use a `LinkedHashMap` ([doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)).

Comment: but... TreeMap uses natural ordering... OP: what do you mean by 'order of the elements'???

Comment: I think what he means by "defined ordering" is that it will use the comparison built into the key's class, or will use a Comparator that you can pass in.

Comment: @broady TreeMap uses natural ordering...unless you provide your own Comparator to the constructor.

Comment: A TreeMap can use any arbitrary comparator for ordering keys

Comment: Natural ordering is used just without a comparator.. I used defined ordering because you can actually specify what kind of ordering you want :)

Comment: I think the OP did hate me :(

Comment: @Jack: There is nothing wrong with your answer, but I felt that the one I accepted was (barely) easier to understand. In fact I upvoted both yours and [the one I accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943973/is-there-such-thing-as-an-arrayset-and-arraymap/3943994#3943994)

Answer (score 3):

You should check the [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/) project, a memory and time efficient Java Collection framework.
It provides an array map implementation, such as [Int2IntArrayMap](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/Int2IntArrayMap.html)

Give it a try! I don't use anymore the standard library, fastutils really make the difference.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

There is an [`ArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html) in the Android support libraries. There are some non-JDK components, but it shouldn't be that difficult to port.

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/util/ArrayMap.java)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and [-Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> This implementation differs from `HashSet` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set.
>
> This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by `HashSet`, without incurring the increased cost associated with `TreeSet`. It can be used to produce a copy of a set that has the same order as the original, regardless of the original set's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Or how about a ListOrderedMap that retains order of the elements. [ListOrderedMap Api](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap.html)

Comment: LinkedHashMap in the standard API does the same and doesn't require you to include a third-party JAR in your project.

Comment: LOM has API extensions that LinkedHashMap can't
duplicate.  Example:  in commons-collections 3.2,
put(int, Object, Object) was added to LOM, which
allows you to insert a mapping at a particular
position.  There are others.