# ArrayMap versus HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, hashmap

what is the main difference with `org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.util.ArrayMap` and `java.util.HashMap`?

Is ArrayMap is thread safe?

In the documentation it is mentioned that Array is best in performance wise.

I don't want to use hashmap or concurrent hashmap. I want to try other like below. which one is best alternative If I consider Thread safety and performance?

```
ArrayMap<String,String> var= new ArrayMap<String,String>();
```

Comment: What is an ArrayMap? Hint: It's not part of the Java standard library

Comment: Your above code won't compile, there is no such thing called `ArrayMap` did you mean `ArrayList`?

Comment: @PradeepSimha - There is something called [ArrayMap](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/com/google/api/client/util/ArrayMap.html). Its just that its not the part of Java SDK. My friends at Google provide this class.

Comment: Its imported from org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.util

Comment: Actually a lot of folks provide it. [Oracle ArrayMap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/javatools/util/ArrayMap.html), [Apaches MyFaces ArrayMap](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/util/ArrayMap.html). The OP needs to mention, which of these is the one referred in the question?!

Comment: I have used  Apaches MyFaces ArrayMap.

Comment: @R.J I think arraymap provided by different vendors have same kind of implementation. If I am not wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943973/is-there-such-thing-as-an-arrayset-and-arraymap/3943993#3943993

Comment: Is arrayMap thread safe?

Comment: @hrv: We have map called ArrayMap

Comment: "They also must provide their own synchronization, if needed" => you have your answer in the javadoc...

Comment: ArrayMap is available in android. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html

is this ArrayMap class you want to compare for your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**HashMap** uses an array underneath so it can never be faster than using an array correctly.

`Random.nextInt()` is many times slower than what you are testing, even using array to test an array is going to bias your results.The reason your array is so slow is due to the equals comparisons, not the array access itself.

An `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface and a `HashMap` implements the `Map` interface. So the real question is when do you want to use a List and when do you want to use a Map. This is where the Java API documentation helps a lot.

**List:**

An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

**Map:**

An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

The list interface `(ArrayList)` is an ordered collection of objects that you access using an index, much like an array (well in the case of `ArrayList`, as the name suggests, it is just an array in the background. You would use an `ArrayList` when you want to keep things in sorted order (the order they are added, or indeed the position within the list that you specify when you add the object).

The `HashMap` implementation uses the hash value of the key object to locate where it is stored, so there is no guarantee of the order of the values anymore. There are however other classes in the Java API that can provide this, e.g. `LinkedHashMap`, which as well as using a hash table to store the key/value pairs, also maintains a List (LinkedList) of the keys in the order they were added, so you can always access the items again in the order they were added (if needed).

**When to use Arrays?**

Never underestimate arrays. Most of the time, when we have to use a list of objects, we tend to think about using vectors or lists. However, if the size of collection is already known and is not going to change, an array can be considered as the potential data structure. It's faster to access elements of an array than a vector or a list. That's obvious, because all you need is an index. There's no overhead of an additional get method call.

Sometimes, it may be best to use a combination of the above approaches. For example, you could use a ArrayList of HashMap to suit a particular need.

Comment: Thats cool.. I to know this... But When it comes to thread safety which will be the best..?

Comment: Hashmap is not thread safe whereas arraylist is. Anything multiple threads can modify should be thread safe. So if many threads can modify the Map, Lists, and Objects in the Lists, then all of those should have thread-safety guards. If only the Map and List instances can be modified concurrently, only they need thread safety. If multiple threads can read everything, but not modify, then you don't need any thread safety.

Comment: Okay, but this does not compare `ArrayMap` with `HashMap`, which is the question. `ArrayMap` is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html