# What are the differences between ArrayList and ArrayMap?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, data-structures

What are the main differences between an `ArrayList` and an `ArrayMap`? Which one is more efficient and more faster for non-threaded applications?
Documents say `ArrayMap` is a generic key->value mapping data structure, So what is the differences between `ArrayMap` and `HashMap`, are both same ?

Comment: `ArrayMap` is a map (key -> value pairs). `ArrayList` is a list (a sequence of items).

Comment: So what is the difference between ArrayMap and HashMap?

Comment: @ucMedia **[`arraymap-versus-hashmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441407/arraymap-versus-hashmap)**

Comment: The [JavaDoc tells you](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html). It's generally slower but aims to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: @NileshRathod That question is about a different class also named `ArrayMap`, so it's not relevant.

Comment: @Michael I already added *another* existing question. In the end, it is about list versus map. Which is something ... explained before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`ArrayMap`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html) keeps its mappings in an array data structure — an integer array of hash codes for each item, and an Object array of the **`key -> value pairs`**.

Where [**`ArrayList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a List. Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null.

**FYI**

**`ArrayMap is a generic key->value`** mapping data structure that is designed to be more memory efficient than a **`traditional HashMap`**.

> Note that ArrayMap implementation is not intended to be appropriate for
>   data structures that may contain large numbers of items. It is
>   generally slower than a traditional HashMap, since lookups require a
>   binary search and adds and removes require inserting and deleting
>   entries in the array. For containers holding up to hundreds of items,
>   the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%.

Comment: And what is the difference between ArrayMap and HashMap?

Comment: @ucMedia ArrayMap is a generic key->value mapping data structure that is designed to be more memory efficient than a traditional HashMap

Comment: @ucMedia **[`arraymap-versus-hashmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441407/arraymap-versus-hashmap)**

Answer (score 1):

FROM DOCS

> [**`ArrayList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

- The `ArrayList` class extends `AbstractList` and implements the List interface. `ArrayList` supports dynamic arrays that can grow as needed.
- Array lists are created with an initial size. When this size is exceeded, the collection is automatically enlarged. When objects are removed, the array may be shrunk.
- Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to store the list. (This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except that it is unsynchronized.)
- The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.
- Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

> [**`ArrayMap`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html)

- ArrayMap is a generic key->value mapping data structure that is designed to be more memory efficient than a traditional HashMap, this implementation is a version of the platform's android.util.ArrayMap that can be used on older versions of the platform. It keeps its mappings in an array data structure -- an integer array of hash codes for each item, and an Object array of the key/value pairs. This allows it to avoid having to create an extra object for every entry put in to the map, and it also tries to control the growth of the size of these arrays more aggressively (since growing them only requires copying the entries in the array, not rebuilding a hash map).

[**`Read Arraymap vs Hashmap`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441407/arraymap-versus-hashmap)

Comment: What Nilesh said is true, however there is one thing to keep in mind, the ArrayList (Which implements the List interface) has order in it, meaning the way your objects are added is the way the objects will be returned when iterating through the collection,                                                       
a Map on the other hand has no natural ordering, so when your adding objects to that collection, your not guaranteed a specific order when iterating through the Collection, e.i. when adding 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 you might get 2, 5, 1, 3, 4.